# What are some conventions to deal with deploying a web app under different root directories?

Tags: java, angularjs, web-applications

I am developing a java/javascript web application with JSPs, servlets, JAX-RS, and AngularJS.  I am pretty new to this kind of stuff.

One problem I've been having is that I need to address url paths from static html, from javascript files, from jsps, and within servlets.  I would like to be able to deploy this web app under different context roots (basically deploy in different folders).  But in order to do this, unless I am mistaken, I must go through all the static files, (javascript and html) and change every link to properly reference resources based on  new root directory.  For the server side files, there are some java convenience methods like ServletContext's getContextPath() which allow me to avoid this.

Are there any conventions or strategies that people use to allow one to easily move a web app to different directories on a site without breaking all the links?  At the moment I am guessing you must do search and replace for all the links.

Maybe put a special tag next to all local links so you know to change it?

Cheers,

Comment: why not use a relative path.  if html is in webcontext root then js could be in js directory, images could be in img dir etc.

Comment: ok, so from a js file you would simply address html files by prepending your url with '../'?  you would only have to worry about changing the links if you moved files relative to each other.  Is this what people usually do?

Comment: usually I do not think that people access html files from js, usually a html will include one or more js and img files.

Comment: Not necessarily, for example angular lets you include other html pages within your current page for templating purposes.  But anyway there are plenty of resources of various types you WILL address from js.

Comment: [for example angular lets you include other html pages within your current page] - surely this would be html in html.  Please educate me as to when you would access a resource from JS.

Comment: @Java1, the HTML appears inside of HTML, but it is specified as a partial in Javascript. But there are other cases when JS would access HTML for a variety of reasons. OP - you should read [this article](http://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2014/03/27/13-step-guide-angularjs-modularization/) for some general thoughts. He has a decent approach in his step 10 for dealing with partials. Although it would require some work to retrofit, it is trivial to add to new development and will make the movement of modules easier.

Answer (score 0):

As Java1 indicates, just use relative paths.

If the resource you are referencing is on the same level as the current web page, you don't need to prepend any path info. For example, if your main web page is loaded from path `http://www.example.com/context/hello.html`, and you have an image folder with path `http://www.example.com/context/image`, you can just load a image from that folder in your html with the relative path `<img src="image/someimage.png">`, without putting hostname or servlet context in your path.

If you are level deeper than the resource you are referencing, use "../" in front of the path.  For example: `<img src="../image/someimage.png">`.  If you are two levels deeper, use `../../image/someImage``, etc.

This holds true not just for images, but for scripts or static html **as long as the web browser is loading the resource.**

The web browser is responsible for converting the relative path to a server path.  If you need to load something from the server side, you will need to use the full path.